# Read csv while grouping rows

Tags: python, csv, grouping, rows

I have a csv file that is exported from an external application as such

```
15/07/2008 2:48:53 PM

Measurement device:; dvp3445
Field detector:; Diode
Reference detector:; Undefined
Scan mode:; Continuous

Points [mm]:
X; Y; Depth; Normalized field; Current field; Ratio
0.0; -109.0; 20.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0
0.0; -108.7; 20.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0
0.0; -108.4; 20.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0
0.0; -108.0; 20.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0
0.0; -107.7; 20.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0


15/07/2008 5:28:50 PM

Measurement device:; dvp3445
Field detector:; Diode
Reference detector:; Undefined
Scan mode:; Continuous

Points [mm]:
X; Y; Depth; Normalized field; Current field; Ratio
0.0; -108.7; 40.0; 1.3; 0; 0.0
0.0; -108.4; 40.0; 1.4; 0; 0.0
0.0; -108.1; 40.0; 1.4; 0; 0.0
0.0; -107.8; 40.0; 1.4; 0; 0.0
0.0; -107.5; 40.0; 1.5; 0; 0.0
0.0; -107.2; 40.0; 1.6; 0; 0.0
0.0; -106.9; 40.0; 1.6; 0; 0.0


15/07/2008 5:28:50 PM

Measurement device:; dvp3445
Field detector:; Diode
Reference detector:; Undefined
Scan mode:; Continuous

Points [mm]:
X; Y; Depth; Normalized field; Current field; Ratio
0.0; -106.6; 40.0; 1.7; 0; 0.0
0.0; -106.3; 40.0; 1.8; 0; 0.0
0.0; -106.0; 40.0; 1.8; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.7; 40.0; 1.9; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.4; 40.0; 2.0; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.1; 40.0; 2.1; 0; 0.0
0.0; -104.8; 40.0; 2.2; 0; 0.0
0.0; -104.5; 40.0; 2.3; 0; 0.0
```

Does anyone of the python csv readers handle this kind  of situation given that the output I am looking for is 3 arrays with each column corresponding to the point headers X; Y; Depth; Normalized field; Current field; Ratio.

I tried to implement this using regex parsing but it didn't work. Can someone share some ideas ?

GT

Comment: try with my solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the reader classes in the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module are initialised with string-iterables, it will suffice to chunk out the appropriate blocks of lines:

```
import csv

f = open('data.txt', 'r')
lines = [l for l in f if len(l.split(';')) == 6]  # filter relevant lines
bounds = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if line[0] == 'X'] + [len(lines)]
bounds = zip(bounds, bounds[1:])  # [(0, 6), (6, 14), (14, 23)]
line_blocks = [lines[start: end] for start, end in bounds]

csv_readers = [csv.DictReader(block, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True) for block in line_blocks]
```

Now each reader is an iterable over `dict` instances with the headers as keys.

```
r = csv_readers[0]
for record in r:
    print record

{'Ratio': '0.0', 'Depth': '20.0', 'Normalized field': '1.3', 'Current field': '0', 'Y': '-109.0', 'X': '0.0'}
{'Ratio': '0.0', 'Depth': '20.0', 'Normalized field': '1.3', 'Current field': '0', 'Y': '-108.7', 'X': '0.0'}
{'Ratio': '0.0', 'Depth': '20.0', 'Normalized field': '1.3', 'Current field': '0', 'Y': '-108.4', 'X': '0.0'}
{'Ratio': '0.0', 'Depth': '20.0', 'Normalized field': '1.3', 'Current field': '0', 'Y': '-108.0', 'X': '0.0'}
{'Ratio': '0.0', 'Depth': '20.0', 'Normalized field': '1.3', 'Current field': '0', 'Y': '-107.7', 'X': '0.0'}
```

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl: but my expected result was 0.0; -106.6; 40.0; `1.7; 0; 0.0
0.0; -106.3; 40.0; 1.8; 0; 0.0
0.0; -106.0; 40.0; 1.8; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.7; 40.0; 1.9; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.4; 40.0; 2.0; 0; 0.0
0.0; -105.1; 40.0; 2.1; 0; 0.0
0.0; -104.8; 40.0; 2.2; 0; 0.0
0.0; -104.5; 40.0; 2.3; 0; 0.0`